# Find all words that match input in array of strings using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a class in JS that holds an array of coding terms. I want to create a prototype function that takes in a user's input and returns up to 5 results matching the input string. If the user starts typing "o" the first 5 "o" search results will be pulled by this function.  My question is, what is the performant way to achieve this if the array is some 6000+ terms in length?

Here is my code:

```
class CodingSearchTerms{


 constructor() {
    this.codingTerms = [
      'oracle erp',
      'oracle exadata',
      'oracle financials',
      'oracle fusion',
      'oracle hcm',
      'oracle identity management',
      'Oracle PL/SQL Developer Certified Associate',
      'oracle rac',
      'Oracle Real Application Clusters 12c Certified Implementation Specialist',
      'oracle rman',
      'Oracle Solaris 11 Installation and Configuration Certified Implementation Specialist',
      'path.js',
      'patience',
      'pbx',
      'pca',
      'pcb',
      'pci dss',
      'pdf object',
      'pdf.js',
      'pdfkit',
      'pdfmake',
      'pedalboard.js',
      'peerjs',
      'pega',
      'pegasus',
      'pencilblue',
      'penetration tester',
    ]
  }

  findTopFiveTerms(userInput) {
    // find top 5 matching terms code
  }
}
```

Comment: you could set an interval that runs every second to check and see if the input data equals to the items in the coding terms array. To check every letter you could split the items in the array then run the interval on the split data.

Comment: First place to start would be a minimum character limit. Then read up on how to use *"debounce"* to minimize queries as typing is going on

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```js
 findTopFiveTerms(userInput) { return this.codingTerms.filter((v, i) => v.includes(userInput)).filter((v, i) => i < 4); }
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please tell me why. Does it not work? Please think about it and edit the post if it is wrong.

Comment: `i < 4` is to limit the array size to 5 elements.

Comment: No, will limit to matches in only the first 5 items in `codingTerms` array and not return anything from the other 5995

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the code to work properly. Is this fine now?

Comment: Could just use slice()